# Build a series of number strings based on combinations of True and False in another column

Tags: excel

Here's the table I'm working with:

[image]

I am manually inputting the "True" in column B for this project. For the example, I manually input column A, but the goal is to get the same results just from referencing column B.

I need it to count up, starting with 166 and add to the number string until it either hits a true, a double true (true back to back), or a double blank (blank cells back to back). For example, the first cell in column B is blank, the second cell is "True", and the third cell is blank - so it input 166, 167. If it went blank > True > True, the input would be 167, 168, 169 in the first three rows.

There can never be more than two trues in a row, only one or two. If there is two blanks in a row then only one number would be input (see 179).

I need to input the same contents (166, 167 for example) until either the blank>true>blank, blank>true>true, or blank>blank condition is met. Then it starts a new string and inputs based on the next condition, and so on.

Apologies for the row #'s being one off if that's confusing... the row numbers have no affect on the #'s in column A, need it to just reference column B.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it to work. Please check out the code below. It should be installed in the code sheet of the worksheet on which you want the result.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Variatus @STO 07 Apr 2020

    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Result As String
    Dim R As Long, Ra As Long

    With Target
        If .Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

        Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1))
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
            Arr = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1)).Value

            For R = 2 To Rng.Rows.Count
                If Result = "" Then Result = ResultString(Result, R, Arr)
                Arr(R, 1) = Result
                Cells(R, 1).Value = Result
                If R < UBound(Arr) Then
                    If Arr(R + 1, 2) = False Then
                        Result = ResultString(Result, R + 1, Arr)
                    End If
                End If
            Next R
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Function ResultString(ByVal Seed As Variant, _
                              ByVal R As Long, _
                              Arr As Variant) As String
    ' Variatus @STO 07 Apr 2020

    Const Start As Integer = 166

    Dim Fun As String
    Dim Sp() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    Sp = Split(Seed, ",")
    Seed = Val(Sp(UBound(Sp))) + 1
    If Err.Number Then Seed = Start
    Fun = Seed

    On Error GoTo 0
    Do While (R + i) < UBound(Arr)
        i = i + 1
        If Arr(R + i, 2) = False Then Exit Do
        Fun = Fun & ", " & CStr(Val(Seed) + i)
    Loop

    ResultString = Fun
End Function
```

The event procedure responds to changes in column B and will build column A according to the entries - True and False (or blank) - found there. The entire column must be rebuilt on each change. Observe the `Const Start As Integer = 166` containing the start number.